# Gemfire Query binding parameters for DATE

Tags: gemfire, geode

I need to filter out the Gemfire region based on date the query is

```
String queryString = SELECT * FROM /exampleRegion WHERE prcs_date =DATE $1;
QueryService queryService = cache.getQueryService();
Query query = queryService.newQuery(queryString);
Object[] params = new Object[1];
params[0] = "2018-05-03";
SelectResults results = (SelectResults)query.execute(params);
```

when i tried to execute it I am getting the following exception

```
QueryInvalidException: Syntax error in query: expecting StringLiteral, found '$'
```

But when I tried to run the hardcoded query `select * from /exampleRegion where prcs_date= DATE '2018-05-03'` I am able to get the results

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to translate a string to a date is to use the to_date function. Here's an example:

`SELECT * FROM /exampleRegion WHERE prcs_date = to_date($1, 'yyyy-MM-dd')`